# React Property Grid with ag-grid component

Tags: reactjs, properties, grid, ag-grid

Can I create property grid with react and ag-grid component such as below?

[image: propertygrid]

I just need plain property grid.

thanks for all replies

Comment: This is possible. As per your screenshot, probably you will need to use row groupings, cellRenderers and other custom functions implemented over default ag-grid ones. However I do not think that this library would be the best solution for your needs (your screen does not show any data presentation component, you do not need to make any sorting, filtering, calculations etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I developed a Property grid with ag-gird. For this, you need to use Tree List and full-width rows.

Render full-width rows(as Expander component so that you can hide/show the remaining children).

Then you can render any custom cell renderer based on some conditions.

You can collapse/expand all rows with collapseAll and expandAll features.